# How to get first, third and fifth Saturday of a month in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have already found a solution to this problem, but it's getting wrong for some condition. Following are my findings:

This code segment is to print the first Saturday of August 2015 and July 2015:

```
$sat = date("F Y",strtotime("2015-08-01"));
echo $fir_sat = "$sat first saturday";
echo " is ".date('d', strtotime($fir_sat));

$sat = date("F Y",strtotime("2015-07-04"));
echo $fir_sat = "$sat first saturday";
echo " is ".date('d', strtotime($fir_sat));
```

Following are the output:

```
August 2015 first Saturday is 08
July 2015 first Saturday is 04
```

But actually it is **01**:

```
August 2015 first Saturday is 01
```

How does it happen? What is the solution?

Based on your feedback's I have tried some coding. Following are my findings. The error happened because of php version.

In lower version of PHP like 5.2.9 the following code is not working

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday of august 2015'));

But in higher version like 5.4 it is wokring

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `of` as

```
echo date('d F Y', strtotime('first saturday of $fir_sat'));
```

> **"ordinal dayname 'of' " does not advance to another day.**

instead of

```
echo date('d F Y', strtotime('$fir_sat first saturday'));
```

> **"ordinal dayname " does advance to another day.**

[**You can check the difference over here**](https://eval.in/410914)

You can also check [**Docs(Notes)**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Hi, i think this is not working. When i echoed this it points to default date, 01 January 1970.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can utilize strtotime function.

```
echo date('d F Y', strtotime('first saturday of August 2015'));
echo "<br>";
echo date('d F Y', strtotime('second saturday of August 2015'));
echo "<br>";
echo date('d F Y', strtotime('fifth saturday of August 2015'));
```

Make sure you are passing proper year and month at the end, based on that it will give you correct date.

Thanks

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday of august 2015'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('third saturday of august 2015'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('fifth saturday of august 2015'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution,tested in my local.

```
$sat = date("d F Y",strtotime("2015-08-01"));
echo $fir_sat = "$sat<br> First saturday";
echo " is ".date('d', ($fir_sat)); 


$thi_sat = strtotime ( '+14 day' , strtotime ( $sat ) ) ;
$thi_sat = date ( 'd' , $thi_sat );
echo "<br>third Saturday at ".$thi_sat;

$fifth_sat = strtotime ( '+28 day' , strtotime ( $sat ) ) ;
$fifth_sat = date ( 'd' , $fifth_sat );
echo "<br>Fifth Saturday at ".$fifth_sat;
```

Out put is:

```
01 August 2015
First saturday is 01
third Saturday at 15
Fifth Saturday at 29
```

This might help.Cheers!!

Comment: updated, generates first, third and fifth saturday as per your requirement. :)